# Можно ли парсить авторизацию?

Tags: php, парсер

Предположим, у нас есть сайт, который парсит данные с другого сайта. Пользователь авторизован на другом сайте и зашел в аккаунт. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при заходе на наш сайт он уже был авторизован. Можно ли это сделать как-то через cURL?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/109700/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если другой сайт принадлежит вам и вы можете внести необходимые правки, то да, вы можете использовать несколько способов. В противном случае это был бы легкий способ угона аккаунта с любого чужого сайта простым CURL и конечно это возможно только при наличии серьезных уязвимостей.

Для первого варианта можно использовать OpenID, OAuth. Или писать свои костыли на ваш выбор.